# Describe all functions holomorphic on open unit disk for which $f(\frac{1}{n}) = -\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Describe all functions holomorphic on open unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{ z : |z| < 1 \}$ for which $f(\frac{1}{n}) = -\frac{1}{n^2}$.

**Attempt:** Suppose $f(z)$ is such a function described in the problem. By $f$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, it is continuous at $0$ so $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(0) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} - \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$. Thus, we can rewrite $f(z) = z^k g(z)$ for some positive integer $k$ with $g(z)$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ with $g(0) \neq 0$.

Since $-\frac{1}{n^2} = f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^k} g(\frac{1}{n}) \Rightarrow - \frac{n^k}{n^2} = g(\frac{1}{n})$ and we know $g(0)$ exists and $g(0) \neq 0$, we must have that $k=2$ with $g(\frac{1}{n}) = -1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, if we consider the constant map $h(z) = -1$ on $\mathbb{D}$, it follows that $h(\frac{1}{n}) = g(\frac{1}{n})$ with $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ having an accumulation point so the identity theorem will give us that $g(z) = -1$. Consequently, the only such map that satisfies the problem above is $f(z) = -z^2$.

Is my proof correct? Would there be a "better" proof? Thank you.

Comment: looks good though you can apply the identity theorem to $g(z)=f(z)+z^2$ directly to conclude is zero everywhere

Comment: @Conrad Thank you!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3597812/42969

Comment: @TheSurgeonofDeath Yes it does and it is great to know another proof. I was not aware of that post. But I do prefer my proof since I don't have the mathematical maturity yet. :P

Comment: Luckily, the comments have verified your proof and the "better proof" you asked for is provided in the other post. Would you have gained anything more from this post being open?